# Show string in an SQL colour scheme in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, user-interface

Is it possible to display a string where the value is an SQL query, in an SQL colour scheme as shown below?

Example

[image]

Comment: I see there is nothing to do with `SQL` then why you tagged `SQL` ?

Comment: You're looking for a syntax highlighting library; here's one I found after 30 seconds with Google: https://github.com/thomasjo/highlight

Comment: The Answer: yes.  Way too broad of a question though.

Comment: I wasn't sure what it was called.  Thanks @RogerLipscombe - got the library and working now as I need it.